# Find how many groups of 3 are in list

Tags: jquery

I have the following list

```
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to use jQuery to find how many groups of 3 li elements are, and use that value further, but cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: give some example, question was not clear

Comment: `$('li').length / 3;`  round up or down depending on need.

Comment: like from my basic example, the result should be 5 (2 groups x 3 li + 1 x 2 li)

Comment: No according to question its need to be 2 only. Your question and your need are far away from each other. Please elaborate properly. answer 5 according to me is misleading

Comment: Result should be 5?? How you calculate it?! @user1822312

Comment: Sorry, result should be 3.

Comment: @user1822312  it will be 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.floor($("li").length / 3)` to find number of packs of 3 `li`s and use `$("li").length % 3` to find single `li`s.

```js
var packOf3  = Math.floor($("li").length / 3);

var singleLi = $("li").length % 3;


console.log("3 packs: ", packOf3);

console.log("Singles: ", singleLi);

console.log("Answer is", packOf3 + (singleLi? 1 : 0))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**

Your answer will be calculated with this

```
console.log("Answer is", packOf3 + (singleLi? 1 : 0))
```